# IOS Swift UISearchBar is there a way to display results in the same View

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have a UISeachBar inside a TableView header is there a way to display the results in the same View that the UISearch bar is in ? I have the base **View** which contains the TableView and in the Header Portion of the TableView I have my SearchBar, when the searchBar is clicked the whole view is hidden and replaced by **View_Design** below . I know that the normal way to fix this is to add another View below the searchBar, however if I do that then the SearchBar will no longer be inside the TableView. Is there anything that I can do to have the SearchBar results display under the searchBar while having the results in the same View. I am using swift 4.

```
  func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
        IsearchBar.showsCancelButton = true

  let Popup = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "View_Design") as! View_Design
        self.addChildViewController(Popup)
        Popup.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(Popup.view)
        Popup.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Why are you adding a new view while searching? Why not use the same tableView to display the filtered data?

Comment: I am new to Swift but How can I add the existing TableView while still showing the UISearchBar

Comment: You don't have to add a new tableView. Instead, use the same tableView to reload filtered data. See this link https://www.raywenderlich.com/157864/uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Both of the TableViews are customs, the main TableView has images and other fields . The TableView for Search just has text.

Comment: Have a look at the link I posted. You can use the same tableView while using different cells in `cellForRow` method depending on whether search is active or not

Comment: See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49079432/tableview-searchbar-for-json-data/49080827#49080827